# How can I find out the exact command line (or task name) of a crashed task?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, windows-error-reporting

Let's say I have 3 tasks in the Windows task scheduler. They run the same app, but with different command line arguments:

- Task A: `myprogram.exe -a`
- Task B: `myprogram.exe -b`
- Task C: `myprogram.exe -c`

The Windows Error Reporting comes up at an irregular interval, because one of the processes that was created from one of these tasks crashed.

I can see that in the event log as well, but I have no idea which of the tasks it is.

Is there a way to see the command line arguments or the task name when Windows Error Reporting catches a crashing process run from Windows Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

The task scheduler has a results column per task.

You can see which task was succesful and which task ended with an error code, to see what task crashed. Of course this only is visible until the task runs again.

If you need a better way to deal with this, consider creating a small launching .cmd file and use that instead of your program.

The .cmd file can then output the time/date of when it was launched to the logfile, and once the program ended, write both the %errorlevel% and the time/date to the logfile indicating when it ended.

A sample of what such .cmd file could look like is this:

```
echo %date% %time% : Program X started >> log.txt
start "" "myprogram.exe -A" /wait
echo %date% %time% : Program with parameters -A terminated with errorcode: %errorlevel% >> log.txt
echo. >>log.txt
```